# ASP NET C# : Singleton with in Queue and thread worker on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I need to create a single class instance in web application that manage a queue of process. This class have multiple thread inside that look for queue and consume it.
What is the best why to do this?

I have apply singleton design pattern, but I don't understand if have to create static or normal queue inside it. Some one can give me an example please?

**SOLUTION**

Ok thank you! This is my singleton class:

```
    public sealed class MyWorkingSingletonClass
    {

    private static readonly ILog LOG = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyWorkingSingletonClass));
    private static MyWorkingSingletonClass instanza;
    private static readonly object lockObject = new object();
    private static ConcurrentQueue<Process> syncCoda = new ConcurrentQueue<Process>();

    private MyWorkingSingletonClass()
    {
    }

    public static MyWorkingSingletonClass Instanza
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (instanza == null)
                    instanza = new PdfDucumentConverter();
                return instanza;
            }
        }
    }



    public void AddProcess(Process p)
    {
        syncCoda.Enqueue(p);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(WorkerTask2);
    }

    public static void WorkerTask2()
    {

        do
        {
            try
            {
                Process p;
                if (syncCoda.TryDequeue(out p))
                {
                    p.Start();
                    p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LOG.Error(ex);
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    }
```

Comment: There are already tools that exist to do this in C#.  You could use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, or you could use `Task`.

Comment: @Servy: how ThreadPool manage threads push tasks and other threads pop task for processing?

Comment: Singleton pattern you applied is not thread-safe with single lock, how to call Start or WorkerTask2, both public?

Comment: Please could you un-answer this question, it's not correct much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to implement new *singleton class* which inherits [Concurrent Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class which is thread-safe queue to ensure it will work in multi-thread environment:

```
public class SingletonConcurrentQueue<T> : ConcurrentQueue<T>
{
    private static readonly SingletonConcurrentQueue<T> 
                                   _instance = new SingletonConcurrentQueue<T>();

    static SingletonConcurrentQueue(){}
    private SingletonConcurrentQueue(){}

    public static SingletonConcurrentQueue<T> Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok! the same class is a queue. But if I want to manage a queue inside? be static? private static ConcurrentQueue<T> _myQueque = new ConcurrentQueue<T>(). Can you give me an example of a list of thread inside that class that use the queue?

Comment: Thanks @CuongLe, looks promising.  I want to create a queue that processes HttpWebRequests, I don't want them to thread out of control.